# RedUcir codigo - ayuda

Tags: programación-funcional

buen día, son novato programando, quisiera saber una manera de reducir mi código, no tengo una idea clara de como hacerlo....
y quisiera una perspectiva diferente....... aqui les pongo una parte del codigo

```
void main()
{
trisb=0x0; // port B configuro como salida
portb=0x0; // port B en 0000000
while(0);
//numero "0"
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1); 
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1); 
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1); 
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1); 
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1); 
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);   
//pausa
    delay_ms(200);
//numero "1"
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un UNO
    set_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
//envia un CERO 
    clear_bit(portb, 0); set_bit(portb, 1); clear_bit(portb,1);
```

en si solo cuenta del 1 al 5.. solo con esas instrucciones, pero quiera saber si hay una manera de reducirlo

Comment: hola, cual lenguaje que usas? por favor anadir en la etiqueta tambien

Comment: es para programar un circuito........ de IDE utilizo SourceBoost........... esta en lenguaje C